# altcoin execoin miner is infected?

Tags: altcoin, mining-software, virus, malware

looking for asic-proof alt-coins, I found one called EXE coin. however, it requires their version of the miner and it says standard miners won't work. firefox/waterfox claims the binary is infected. should I be looking for a different asic-proof alt coin or is that a false positive?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/30336/5464

Answer (score 2):

Often these CPU miners are flagged by specific AV's heuristics, mainly because the program may be an exe with a hidden CPU mining algorithm within, which if it was any other exe like an image viewer, this suggests nefarious mining.

That being said, altcoin wallets and miners are notorious for malicious code, and Bitcoin is the target of more than [100 types of BTC stealing malware](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9246692/Bitcoin_malware_count_soars_as_cryptocurrency_value_climbs).

Since cgminer/cudaminer uses *scrypt-n* simply find a miner which has been vouched for (ie checksum of the exe should match).